# Install 16.04LTS using VMware WORKSTATION 12 PRO

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, 64-bit, virtualization, vmware

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using VMware just to verify if the 16.04 OS will work properly on my laptop machine which is a bit old.

For that I installed VMware WORKSTATION 12 PRO, and I downloaded `ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` file from the official Ubuntu page.

My machine supports Intel VT-x technology and is already enabled, as my current OS (14.04LTS) is a 64-bit version.

The problem is that VMware, somehow, doesn't recognize that my laptop can run 64-bit OS.

I already selected the `Preferred mode` (from Hardware -> Processors -> Virtualization Engine) to be `Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI` but when trying to install the OS, this error is displayed:

[image]

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: 1) Are you sure you enabled virtualization in the BIOS? **2) Just because 16.04 runs in a VM does not mean it will run fine on the bare metal. You'd be much better off just trying out the live session.**

Comment: @AndroidDev 1) Yes, I'm sure. The `Enabled` option was selected for the virtualization. 2) It's a bit tricky here. I'm trying 16.04 through a VMware because in my actual OS I'm having a lot of stuff, and I don't want to re-install/re-copy it again, if, for some reason, 16.04 would not run on my laptop.

Comment: You're missing my point. The fact that an OS can run inside of a VM does not mean that it will run well on the actual hardware.

Comment: @AndroidDev I've understood your point. But my question is whay VMware isn't able to install 16.04 LTS 64-bit, even though my actual OS is a 64-bit version, and with VT-x technology being enabled?

Comment: Try toggling "IO-APIC" in System Settings of the VM

Comment: @AndroidDev I can't find this option. Can you provide more info about it?